# How to hide macro animation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a Google Sheets macro to copy info from one tab to another, but when I run this, it shows all the steps on the screen. Is there a way to hide them?

This is the script that was created from the macro:

```
function Step1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Working Shift Report'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('✔️Overview'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Working Shift Report\'!A3:A1000').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Working Shift Report'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C3').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('✔️Overview'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Working Shift Report\'!C3:C1000').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D4:J498').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D4:J498').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(6, true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H4').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues(['Yes'])
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(8, criteria);
};'''
```

Comment: As expected, code you execute does exactly what your wrote, not what you actually meant. So unless you _want_ the code to select a cell, then do not call methods that select a cell. There are other methods to reference a Range or Cell beyond `getActiveRange` (and they're all highly preferred instead of it, actually). You should review the Apps Script API reference.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, you are specifically telling Google Sheets to perform all of those tasks. Since you recorded it from a Macro, it is customary for the actions to be performed exactly as you planned it. All of the "activate"s and the "setActiveSheet" are just examples of that

If you want all this to run in the background you will need to rewrite your code so that it doesn't perform all the selecting and highlighting and transitioning between the different sheets. I could help rewrite it but I don't know the structure of your data or what sheets you have